# Relationship between "גולגולת" (skull) and "גלגל" (wheel)

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, hebrew

Both "[גולגולת](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%AA#Aramaic)" (skull) and "[גלגל](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9C)" (wheel) are listed, on Wiktionary, as coming from the shared root [ג־ל־ג־ל](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%92%D6%BE%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%92%D6%BE%D7%9C#Hebrew). All of the other words except for גולגולת have clear relationships to rotating (to roll, cylinder, wheel, etc.). There's also the word [גָּלִיל](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C), "cylinder", and Wiktionary lists that as being "related" -- but I'm curious what that means, is it just superficially similar? Did they influence each other? Or do they derive from a shared stem? Thanks.

Comment: If this turns out to be a coincidence, heads will roll...

Comment: Roll -> round -> skull seems like an easy semantic shift.

Comment: Oh, there is that. I figured that it would be rotate -> neck (head) -> skull. But, either way, I was hoping for some confirmation one way or another. I don't actually know Hebrew, but I thought maybe someone on here could consult a Hebrew etymological dictionary or something.

Comment: Seems like a borrowing from PIE or the opposite.

Comment: @Anixx. What makes you think that?

Comment: @fdb PIE kʷékʷlos "wheel" looks similar, and it is reduplication of kʷel- (so, originally it could be kʷelkʷl-). The Semitic root with four consonants is untypical, so, could be a borrowing.

Comment: @fdb well, even Wikitionary says it is proposed to be a borrowing PIE-> Sumerian, Aramaic, Hebrew and proto-Kartvelian. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/k%CA%B7%C3%A9k%CA%B7los

Comment: Any proposal of a borrowing from Proto-IE to Sumerian is fraught by numerous historical, geographic and chronological problems.

Comment: @Anixx This is a reduplicated root in Hebrew - this pattern is very productive in Hebrew - there is no need to invoke borrowing unless there is other evidence. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%92%D6%BE%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%92%D6%BE%D7%9C